# Changing date format in file name

Tags: windows-7

I have a number of files that contain the date in the following format: dd-mm-yyyy, I'd like to change the date part in the name to a different format: yyyy-mm-dd.
Any ideas? I'm no expert in different shell engines, can dos do the trick?

Comment: Is that the full file name, or are there other characters in it, presumably an extension at least? If so, is the date in a fixed position within the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free Windows tool called Bulk Rename Utility (first Google result, not sure if links are allowed here) that should help. If the date appears in the same position in all the files you can use the "Move" ability for each field (select all the files in the folder to get a live preview of the new filenames). Otherwise a Regular Expression/RegEx replace would do the trick. Something like Find: `(.*)(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})(.*)` Replace with either: `\1\4-\3-\2\5` or: `$1$4-$3-$2$5` depending on how it works (I don't have a Windows machine to test it on at the moment).